# SQL 'group by' equivalent query

Tags: sql, group-by

I've seen the following example:

Let T be a table with 2 columns - [id,value] (both int)

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM T t2 where T.value=t2.value);
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM T GROUP BY value
```

What is going on behind the scene? How can we refer to T1.value?
What is the meaning of `T1.value=t2.value`?

Comment: wasn't it "select * from T T1 where"? (you missed T1 there)

Comment: Is still wrong and I dont think those are equivalent, where you get that example?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T GROUP BY value` would be an illegal query due to missing aggregate function for column `id`.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. Edited again.

Comment: Sorry user, so many things are wrong I think you should start with a basic sql course first. For example the numbers of field on each query are different so you cant compare those

Comment: "What is the meaning of T1.value=t2.value" - this is a co-related sub query

Answer (score 0):

@JuanCarlosOropeza is correct, your premise is false. Those are not equivalent queries. The second query should error out. But more to the point. The purpose of the WHERE clause in the subquery is to restrict the rows in the subquery to the id from the outer query.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the WHERE clause. But HOW does it works?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "how". It's fairly obvious that one reference is to the value outside the subquery and the other is a reference to the value inside the subquery because of the different aliases.

Answer (score 0):

For what's going on behind the scenes, use the explain plan, which provides information about how the optimizer decides to get the data your query asks for.